# Only last insert statement is executed

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm fairly new to SQL and I'm trying to insert a bunch of INSERT statements into the table. 
I'm using SQL Developer and Oracle 11g.

My tables:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE friendlist AS VARRAY(20) OF VARCHAR2(50);
/

create or replace type table fbuser(fbid varchar(10) not null enable,firstname varchar(30),lastname varchar(30),dob
date,birthcity varchar(30),birthstate varchar(25),friends friendlist,primary key(fbid));
/
```

And my insert statements:

```
insert into fbuser values('f1','abhinav','cheatham',to_date('01-jul-1969','dd-mon-yyyy'),'lake city','fl',friendlist('f2','f7','f9'));
/

insert into fbuser values('f2','abhishek','deponto',to_date('05-feb-1984','dd-mon-yyyy'),'adak','ak',friendlist('f1','f6','f9','f16','f18'));
/

insert into fbuser values('f3','aldrich','chapel',to_date('27-may-1988','dd-mon-yyyy'),'vernon hills','il',null);
/
```

I've tried without the / too. But it's giving me the same error. Where am I going wrong? And can you suggest a good tutorial/site from where I can learn this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: which error do you get?

Comment: I dont get any error but only my last insert statement gets executed. When I do select * from fbuser, I get data only from last insert stmt.

Comment: did you commit everything?

Comment: look into this http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/questions/insert_rows.php

Comment: Yes, committed everything.

Comment: Ok, I deleted the last insert query and nothing is getting inserted now (yes, dropped all tables and re ran the query)

Comment: You can try to run `SHOW ERRORS;` to see what happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert multiple rows using the following syntax:

```
INSERT ALL
  INTO mytable (column1, column2, column3) VALUES ('val1.1', 'val1.2', 'val1.3')
  INTO mytable (column1, column2, column3) VALUES ('val2.1', 'val2.2', 'val2.3')
  INTO mytable (column1, column2, column3) VALUES ('val3.1', 'val3.2', 'val3.3')
SELECT NULL FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you were able to successfully execute that CREATE TABLE statement - it's not valid syntax on my system (11gR2). I had better luck with this:

```
create table fbuser(fbid varchar2(10) not null enable
     , firstname varchar2(30), lastname varchar2(30), dob date
     , birthcity varchar2(30), birthstate varchar2(25)    
     , friends friendlist, primary key (fbid));
```

Then the inserts go as they should.

The / characters after the inserts will cause each insert to be executed twice.  Either terminate them with a semicolon or with a /, but not both.

Comment: Thanks! But how will changing varchar to varchar2 solve the issue. Are you implying that varchar2 isnt supported in 11gR2?  I'll try out the / hint.

Comment: @PRamesh, it is hard to figure out why your issue happens, given the code posted. Since the `CREATE ... fbuser ...` creates neither a type nor a table.

Comment: And `varchar2` is used instead of `varchar` because Oracle has been saying they reserve the right to change the behavior of `varchar` to make it ANSI complient. (They have been saying that for **years**) So everyone uses `varchar2` so that there applications will still work *airquote* when the behavior of `varchar` changes. *end airquote*

Comment: Thank you! I have tried implementing them by changing everything to varchar2 and I still face the same issue. Anything else I need to do?